# Can I write my article has been selected for a best research award?

Tags: publications, research-process, cv, awards

One of my articles has been published today. I have got an email from an international awards team that my article has been provisionally selected for Research Awards and recommended by their scientific committee. Now my question is can I write it in my CV even if I don't get an award?

Comment: This sounds suspicious. Why only “provisionally”? What needs to happen in order to get the award non-provisionally? I suspect they’ll be asking you for money, which means it’s 100% a scam. Even if they don’t ask for money right away, be on your guard unless you have a very clear idea of who is giving the award and what is motivating them to do so.

Comment: @DanRomik, this only lacks a sentence from being an answer.

Comment: @Buffy thanks, but it doesn’t really address OP’s actual question (about which I don’t have much of an opinion) so it makes more sense to me as a comment.

Comment: @DanRomik. How about "Yes you _can_ but consider whether you _should_". Then everything else. I hate to steal your words, but couldn't do better than what you say.

Comment: @Buffy thanks for the suggestion. I’ve said what I had to say. If you want to add something to it, in an answer or comment, that’s your right. I give you free rein to include my comment (verbatim, or paraphrased, as you prefer) in an answer if you feel that serves a useful purpose.

Comment: Assuming it is a team that is linked to the journal: It could be nominated; this can be mentioned. Provisionally selected, probably not. That's not an official status, it might be in the narrower panel selection, but is not really a nomination. Better err on side of caution. If it is some random selection team: probably just a scam. You do not get prizes out of thin air.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can do that, but I'd suggest caution until you know a lot more. Perhaps you should, at least, wait or explore further.

Quoting a comment by Dan Romik:

> This sounds suspicious. Why only “provisionally”? What needs to happen in order to get the award non-provisionally? I suspect they’ll be asking you for money, which means it’s 100% a scam. Even if they don’t ask for money right away, be on your guard unless you have a very clear idea of who is giving the award and what is motivating them to do so.

I agree that this seems very scammy.

But if it proves to be valid and it is awarded to another, then it is probably OK to say that the article were a finalist or some-such. But beware. Yellow flags at least. Maybe red.

---

Hats off to Dan Romik who provides the core idea here.

Comment: I have looked into google and I am sure it's a scam. But I already filled a form that needs all my information and submitted it (My CV, certificates, and all ). Now I am worried about what kind of troubles I can face in the future. Is there any way I can take any action?

Comment: Don't pay them when they ask for the money.

Comment: You could ask them to withdraw your paper. I doubt they will comply. Watch out for phishing emails from them and others.